# How can I filter posts by category on a PHP blog (non-wordpress)?

Tags: php

I am creating a project where I have created a system that allows a user to create and publish blog posts. I want to be able to have a drop down function that will filter and display posts by a specific category they are tagged with. How would I go about doing that?

This is not a WordPress site, and any research I've been doing on my own has mainly turned up results for WordPress sites.

If anyone could help me or at least point me in a good direction, that would be great. I'm fairly new to working with PHP so I will take any help I can get.

Here is the part of the index.php where the posts are being displayed:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="centertext">
            <h1>Posts</h1>

            <?php
            while ($query->fetch()):
        $lastspace = strrpos($description, '');
        ?>
        <!-- THIS IS THE STRUCTURE FOR EACH POST /-->
        <article>
            <div class="preview">
                <div class="ptop">
                    <?php echo "<img src='admin/images/".$image."' width='100%' height='100%' >";?>
          <div class="basicinfo">
            <h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
            <?php echo $category?>
          </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pbottom">
          <p><?php echo substr($description, $lastspace).'...<br><br><a href="post.php?id='.$post_id.'">VIEW POST</a>'?></p>
        </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile?> 

        </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the only other PHP I have at the top of the file:

```
<?php
include('includes/db_connect.php');

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, image, LEFT(description, 300) AS description, category FROM post INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=post.category_id order by post_id desc limit $start, $per_page");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $image, $description, $category);

?>
```

The following are the post and categories tables from my database:

**POST**

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `posted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `photo_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(300) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**CATEGORIES**

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I think that it is better to help if you could able to mention about your database schema.

Comment: I added the tables I am using from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

On the page you need a `<select>` with the different categories available.  When they choose one, they are redirected to `yoursite.com/index.php?category=xyz`) where xyz is the category they chose.

In your PHP query you have to add: `WHERE category='$_GET["category"]'` (be sure to sanitize this value for security, with something like mysql_real_escape_string() or PDO).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I am currently working with it and I am running into a couple issues. When I try to manually add the `WHERE category='$_GET["category"]'` in my query, it keeps returning with a parse error for syntax no matter how I write it. any suggestions?

Comment: $queryString = "SELECT post_id, title, image, LEFT(description, 300) AS description, category
FROM post
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=post.category_id
WHERE category = '" . $_GET["category"] . "'
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT $start, $per_page";

$query = $db->prepare($queryString);

Comment: Add small pieces of complexity one at a time.  First write the SQL statement directly into your SQL client until you get it working.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also I tried going to that chat room link you provided, but sadly I do not yet have 20 or higher reputation to be able to talk in there.

Comment: I'm heading there now

Answer (score 0):

First I'd determine the database model. Either you build a n-to-n model or a 1-to-n model. In a 1-to-n model any post can only have one category, in a n-to-n model posts can have multiple categories.

Next I'd determine how complex I'd want the user interface. Essentially the sky is the limit, but keep your audience in mind. You could e.g. just allow one category to be selected, or you could allow multiple ones being selected. If you allow multiple: do you then want that the entry has to have all categories to be included ("and" logic) or allow any post that has any of the categories ("or" logic), a lot of those choices also depend on how many entries you have.

Once you have that laid out, it becomes much simpler to implement it:

- the user interface determines how your form should look like
- the logic and database model determine the sql queries you need
- and then it's only displaying the entries you get back from the database ...